# Can intercept and regression coefficients (Beta values) be very high?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I have 38 variables, like oxygen, temperature, pressure, etc and have a task to determine the total yield produced every day from these variables. When I calculate the regression coefficients and intercept value, they seem to be abnormal and very high (Impractical). For example, if 'temperature' coefficient was found to be +375.456, I could not give a meaning to them saying an increase in one unit in temperature would increase yield by 375.456g. That's impractical in my scenario. However, the prediction accuracy seems right. I would like to know, how to interpret these huge intercept( -5341.27355) and huge beta values shown below. One other important point is that I removed multicolinear columns and also, I am not scaling the variables/normalizing them because I need beta coefficients to have meaning such that I could say, increase in temperature by one unit increases yield by 10g or so. Your inputs are highly appreciated!

```
modl.intercept_
Out[375]: -5341.27354961415

modl.coef_
Out[376]: 
array([ 1.38096017e+00, -7.62388829e+00,  5.64611255e+00,  2.26124164e-01,
        4.21908571e-01,  4.50695302e-01, -8.15167717e-01,  1.82390184e+00,
       -3.32849969e+02,  3.31942553e+02,  3.58830763e+02, -2.05076898e-01,
       -3.06404757e+02,  7.86012402e+00,  3.21339318e+02, -7.00817205e-01,
       -1.09676321e+04,  1.91481734e+00,  6.02929848e+01,  8.33731416e+00,
       -6.23433431e+01, -1.88442804e+00,  6.86526274e+00, -6.76103795e+01,
       -1.11406021e+02,  2.48270706e+02,  2.94836048e+01,  1.00279016e+02,
        1.42906659e-02, -2.13019683e-03, -6.71427100e+02, -2.03158515e+02,
        9.32094007e-03,  5.56457014e+01, -2.91724945e+00,  4.78691176e-01,
        8.78121854e+00, -4.93696073e+00])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very unlikely that all of these variables are linearly correlated, so I would suggest that you have a look at simple non-linear regression techniques, such as Decision Trees or Kernel Ridge Regression. These are however more difficult to interpret.

Going back to your issue, these high weights might well be due to there being some high amount of correlation between the variables, or that you simply don't have very much training data.
If you instead of linear regression use Lasso Regression, the solution is biased away from high regression coefficients, and the fit will likely improve as well.

A small example on how to do this in `scikit-learn`, including cross validation of the regularization hyper-parameter:

```
from sklearn.linear_model LassoCV

# Make up some data
n_samples = 100
n_features = 5
X = np.random.random((n_samples, n_features))
# Make y linear dependent on the features
y = np.sum(np.random.random((1,n_features)) * X, axis=1)

model = LassoCV(cv=5, n_alphas=100, fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(X,y)
print(model.intercept_)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :). I will do lasso and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Hi, I did what you said. Now, beta values and intercept look reasonable, Thank you. But most of my beta coefficients tend to be -zero, which I wouldn't like. I would like to have all these variables in the equation if possible :). Could you help me with it?

Comment: This is how the coef look like now:[ 0.74321934, -0.        ,  2.3479449 , -1.39034172,  0.43315551,
        0.33641404, -0.04482985,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        , -0.        , -0.        , -0.        ,
       -0.        , -0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ,
       -0.        , -0.        , -0.        , -0.        , -0.        ,
        0.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.01676537, -0.00663812,
       -0.        , -0.        ,  0.00600775,  0.        , -0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]

Comment: It could be that the alpha values (regularization parameters) that is used in the CV is not optimal. You can specify a list yourself with the `alphas` keyword. If you change the alpha value, you will get more or less sparse solutions. But in general you would want the data to speak for itself and not enforce what you think is reasonable. It is likely that the features with a coefficient of 0 is just not very important for making predictions.

Comment: That makes sense :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linear regression, the formula looks like this (y= target, x= features inputs):

```
y= x1*b1 +x2*b2 + x3*b3 + x4*b4...+ c
```

where b1,b2,b3,b4... are your modl.coef_. AS you already realized one of your bigges number is `3.319+02 = 331` and the intercept is also quite big with -5431.
As you already mentioned the coeffiecient variables means how much the target variable changes, if the coeffiecient feature changes with 1 unit and all others features are constant.

so for your interpretation, the higher the absoult coeffienct, the higher the influence of your analysis. But it is important to note that the model is using a lot of high coefficient, that means your model is not depending only of one variable